# Is $F\subset l_\infty$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $F$ be the set of all $x\in l_\infty$ ($l_\infty$ is the set of all bounded real sequences) such that $x_n=0$ for all but finitely many $n$. Is $F$ closed?

**My attempt:**

A theorem in my textbook states that the following are equivalent:

(i) $F$ is closed.

(ii) If a sequence $(a_n)\subset F$ converges to some point $a\in l_\infty$, then $a\in F$.

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of points (sequences) in $F$. My intuition tells me that (ii) is true but I don't know how to prove it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: it's false.

Comment: I guess I could use the sequence of sequences $(a_n)$ where the the first $n$ terms of $a_n$ are $1$ and the rest are $0$. Then $(a_n)\to(1, 1, 1, \ldots)$, which is in $l_\infty$ but not in $F$. Would that work?

Comment: Not quite, this doesn't converge in the $\ell_\infty$ topology.

Comment: No, because $a_n\not\to(1,1,\cdots)$: notice that $\lVert a_n-(1,\cdots)\rVert_\infty=1$ for all $n$. But a more accurate choice of limit point works.

Answer (score 1):

A first attempt might be to use the following:

Let $A_k$ be the sequence $1^k0^\infty$, in other words, $(A_k)_i=1$ for $1\leq i\leq k$ and $(A_k)_i=0$ for all $i>k$.

It's easy to see that $A_k\in F$, and we might hope that $A_k\rightarrow 1^\infty$, i.e., the sequence of $1$'s, but the problem is that the $\ell_\infty$ distance between $A_k$ and $F$ is always $1$, so the sequence doesn't converge to all $1$'s.

This, however, gives an idea for a sequence that will work, what must change is that the distance between the desired limit must decrease as $k$ increases.  Therefore, we try the following:

> $$B_k=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{i}&i\leq k\\0&i>k\end{cases}.$$  Each $B_k$ is in $F$ and the $B_k$'s converge to $$\left(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},\dots\right),$$which is not in $F$.